# Timer task that will stop for an "n" time after runs for "x" time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I have a JavaScript task that requires me to create a timer that will stop "n" seconds after "x" seconds.
This is where i am now:

```
    let timerDelay = setTimeout(function{
        console.log('will stop for 59 seconds after 3 seconds');
    }, 3000);
```

I am a beginner and will really appreciate your help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will call a function doSomething() after waiting x miliseconds, then n miliseconds.

```
function nAfterX(n,x) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      doSomething()
    },n)
  },x)
}
```

But that's no different than calling a function after n+x miliseconds. I suspect you're looking for something combined with [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)